# Is there a simple way to test a migration before running it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rails-migrations

In other words I'd like to know the best way to make sure that **self.down** *actually* rolls back **self.up** *before* running the **migration** in question.

What can I do if I need to rollback a migration but **self.down** doesn't serve the purpose?

Which is the best practice when dealing with potentially destructive migrations?
Just a database backup?

Thanks,
Duccio.

Comment: You should always take a back up when running migrations in production, this is just a good practice as you never know what might go wrong, what happens if the power goes out half way through the migration being run? Better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be developing on a development database which should not contain live data. Therefore it should not matter if the data is destroyed as you can easily generate it again?

A database backup might be appropriate if you find yourself in a situation where your development data is important but not ideal.

Comment: Yes, I am developing in a development environment. In the current task my development data is important inasmuch as I need it to understand if **self.down** makes its job. The fact is: if I ran **self.up**, and than a _wrong_ **self.down** without making a database backup before, than It'll be harder for me to fix and test self.down because the initial state (the database before the wrong rollback) will be altered. So I guess that in such cases is worth making a database backup... But the ideal situation, I agree, is to have script-generated dummy data to easily restore _each_ previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Typically migrations should contain only schema changes. In that case it should be very safe & easy to run the migrations in the dev/test environment. If something goes wrong you can alway re-create the database and populate it with some test data. But if you have some data related migrations to be tested, things might go wrong when you actually run them on production.

In that case as you mentioned database backup is what you should rely on. Come with a proper & quick restore mechanism before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the migrations behave as you want you should experiment in your development environment.

Run the command

```
rake -T
```

to show you the available tasks such as

```
rake db:migrate
```

or

```
rake db:rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

Each migration runs inside a transaction. Keep that in mind. That means that if something would go wrong inside a single migration, the migration is rolled back (and if there are any following they are not executed).

To test migrations, be it `up` or `down` I insert a lot of puts-statements, to check everything has worked has supposed to, and then in my last line I raise an exception. This will make rails think the migration has failed, and it will rollback the operation (as if it never happened).

When I am sure everything works as it should, I remove the raise line and let the migration really work.
In your case, you would test with the raise, remove the raise and NOT run it again I assume :)

Hope this helps.